# Kotlin: How to get a file's (IMAGE) creation date?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I cannot understand exactly where I made a stupid mistake. I would be very grateful for the advice

```
val f:File = File("drawable/paystack_mark.png")
// val path:Path =  Paths.get("drawable/new_logo.jpg")
val attr = Files.readAttributes<BasicFileAttributes>(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes::class.java)
```

or

```
val path:Path =  Paths.get("drawable/new_logo.jpg")
val attr = Files.readAttributes<BasicFileAttributes>(path, BasicFileAttributes::class.java)
```

I cannot understand exactly where I made a stupid mistake. I would be very grateful for the advice

Comment: What is the current behaviour (error? no output? wrong output?) and what is the desired one?

Comment: ERROR :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method toPath()Ljava/nio/file/Path; in class Ljava/io/File; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.io.File' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

Comment: So the second example doesn't throw an exception? What does it do instead?

Comment: yeah, i din't get , can you please show me small example to read properties of image form kotlin

Comment: `val f:File = File("drawable/paystack_mark.png")` You are using an invalid File path. Files in drawable are resources. I think that even if you use valig resources code there is no file date . Not sure.

Comment: yes..  how can i add proper path form mobile device

Comment: There is no 'proper' file path as drawable is a resource. I already told you that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is work for me and thank you**

// read image from gallary or you can give direct path

```
        getImage()// read image
        val contentURI = data?.getData()
        var imageFile = File(contentURI?.let { getRealPathFromURI(it) })
        val lastModifiedDate: Date =  Date(imageFile.lastModified())
        println("creation time: " + attr.creationTime())
```

// get Native URI Function

```
private fun getRealPathFromURI(contentURI: Uri): String {
    var getApplicationContext = getContext()?.getContentResolver();
    var result: String
    var cursor: Cursor? =
        context?.getContentResolver()?.query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath().toString();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        val idx: Int = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is working fine, I have tried it on windows with a valid path to a .png file.

This is how I used it (just printed the `attr.creationTime()`):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val path: Path =  Paths.get("M:\\y\\path\\to\\the\\image.png")
    val attr = Files.readAttributes<BasicFileAttributes>(path, BasicFileAttributes::class.java)
    println("creation time: " + attr.creationTime())
}
```

The output was just

```
creation time: 2018-03-16T13:11:57.40283Z
```

Keep in mind that you are coding for Android, so maybe the `String`-versions of the paths are different (see the backslashes for the path on a windows machine).

Comment: btn1.setOnClickListener {
            val path: Path =  Paths.get("E:\\image\\one.jpg")
            val attr = Files.readAttributes<BasicFileAttributes>(path, BasicFileAttributes::class.java)
            Log.d("tetttete : ","ssss ${attr.creationTime()}")
            println("creation time: " + attr.creationTime())

//            PickimageFromGallery()
        } this is ok or can i call separate method

Comment: @MaheshGv Sorry, what is this code-comment supposed to mean?

Comment: @MaheshGv I think you need to use a URI for files on Android devices, but I am not sure. What's not working?

Comment: `"E:\\image\\one.jpg"`. That is a Windows path. Not existing on Android devices. Android does not work with drive letters either.

Comment: yesss, how to add PickimageFromGallery() means mobile gallery image path to Paths.get("HERE") can you please i need to like that

Comment: Why did you mark this answer as correct? It's completely false as you want something for a resource.

Comment: @blackapps Should work with a URI to the file... by the way, it was nearly impossible to give a correct answer to a question missing most of the important information ;-)

Comment: Feel sorry to tell you but your code will never work for a resource file.

Comment: its working but i din't get for my perspective it's k, tell me how to provide device path if understand

Comment: @blackapps no problem... vote the answer down if you know it's wrong and provide a correct one, I may vote that one up then ;-)

Comment: Thank you. That's Fair enough. But lets first see how the communication with OP ends.

Comment: @blackapps Sure, that's mandatory anyway... OP has to provide more detailed information.

Comment: require API level 26+